# Equivalent of Matlab find function for C arrays

Tags: c, search, matlab

I need the equivalent of the Matlab `find` function ([reference](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/find.html)) in C for arrays:

> ind = find(X) locates all nonzero elements of array X, and returns the
>   linear indices of those elements in vector ind. If X is a row vector,
>   then ind is a row vector; otherwise, ind is a column vector. If X
>   contains no nonzero elements or is an empty array, then ind is an
>   empty array.

A trivial untested example:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
int main()
{
   /* Initialize variables */
   int x[25];
   int y[25];

   /* initialize random seed: */
   srand ( time(NULL) );

   /* Fill arrays with stuff */
   for (i=0;i<25;i++)
   {
      x[i] = rand();
      y[i] = rand();
   }

   /* Find */
   ind = find((x-y) > 0); // Need to figure out how to do this
   }
}
```

Now the kicker is I can't use Boost or C++ containers like `vector` due to project constraints.

Comment: My guess is you'll have to roll your own.

Comment: @Dima, that was my original guess and hoping Stack Exchange can prove me wrong.

Comment: @Dorgan, that is why its trivial and what I get for quickly coding something up untested on the fly :p

Comment: Just being a lame smartass - don't mind me here.  I'll go ahead and remove my comment...

Comment: It's just a simple `for` loop, you could have written it 100 times and it would take less time than coming here searching for it! :))

Comment: @Shahbaz, but then I would miss out on the fun of Stack Exchange and the quest of an elegant solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are restricted to "vanilla C" (which seems to be the case, from your question) there's nothing like that built-in, you have to write your own version of such function.

But from what I see from your example you need something different than a `find` function, you want to find the elements differing into `x` and `y`. If you strive for flexibility it could be a good idea to write a generic function that checks the given predicate (passed as a function pointer) on two arrays. On the other hand, since in C we have only function pointers (and not functors) performance may suffer.

Answer (score 1):

This should do something close to what you want - returns number of non-zero elements that it has placed in outArray for you.  Not quite the same calling signature, but should do what you want.  Untested :)

```
size_t find(int *inArray, int *outArray, size_t arraySize)
{
  size_t numElements = 0;
  for(int i=0; i<arraySize; i++)
  {
    if(inArray[i])
    {
       outArray[numElements++] = inArray[i];
    }
  }

  return numElements;
}
```

Comment: I'd use `size_t` for `arraySize`, `numElements` and the return type of `find`.

Comment: @MichaelDorgan: if we want to pre-allocate space for `outArray`, the worst case dictates using an array as big as the original `inArray`. How can we be space-efficient without making a double pass over the input array?

Comment: We already need to know how big the original is anyways for it to exist.  Just use that size when creating the new one.

Comment: @Armo, what exactly were your edits?  It appears identical to me, but shows something changed...